# Force embedded youtube video to HD 5K (2020)

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have tried to embed a video with the parameter: `vq=hd2880`.

And it does not work. By default it is always "Automatic: 720".

I have tried different values.

The src of iframe:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/[code]?vq=hd1080
https://www.youtube.com/embed/[code]?vq=hd1440    (HD)
https://www.youtube.com/embed/[code]?vq=hd2160    (4K)
https://www.youtube.com/embed/[code]?vq=hd2880    (5K)
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding mobile devices: Described in the YouTube documentation, they do not support forcing the quality anymore. I hope anyone comes up with a solution, but for now you cannot change it. See https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/91449 for more info.

edit; I know this is not the answer you wanted of course. We are going to implement Plyr to overcome these issues. Maybe this can help you too.